# jquery: on('click', ...) doesn't work, on('mouseenter', ...) does

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

If have a weird problem, hope you guys can help me here.

In my javascript code I create a div with

```
<div class="..." id="getMoreOfX"><span class="...">More info</span></div>
```

and just below I try to attach a event handler to it with:

```
$(document).on('click', '#getMoreOfX', function(){
  alert("Click: " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

No errors are thrown, but it doesn't do *anything*. The weird thing though, is that merely changing 'click' into 'mouseenter' (or 'mouseleave' for that matter) does cause it to do what it should. Especially this last property confuses me.

Any idea on what may be causing this?

N.B. jquery version is 1.7 and I have tested this in FF, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/MdGCG/). Something else is wrong.

Comment: Do you have other event handlers bound to elements inside that `<div>` that `return false;` as part of the callback function? If so they'll prevent event propagation and as a result break your event delegation.

Comment: I agree, I dumped it directly into a JSFiddle as well, no problems on Firefox 17 (http://jsfiddle.net/acjohnson55/WWdsf/).  It would help if you can produce a JSFiddle that replicates your problem.

Comment: Why don't you show what you originally had with the building of ids dynamically before you replaced it with "X". I bet the error is somewhere in that.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation in jQuery works based on the principle that events in JavaScript bubble (or propagate) up the DOM tree all the way to the document. However, if you have event handlers on elements at a lower level in the DOM that prevent that propagation from happening - either by calling `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` - then the event delegation will no longer work.

For example, if I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Testing event delegation <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Click me" id="test-button"/>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the following jQuery:

```
$('#outer').on('click', '#inner', function(e) {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Then clicking anywhere inside that `<div id="inner">` will result in `inner` being output to the console. However, if I add the following event handler to the button:

```
$('#test-button').click(function(e) {
 return false; 
});
```

Then clicking on the text continues to function as before - `inner` is output to the console - but clicking on the button will result in nothing being output because the event propagation has been prevented.

This can be observed in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qHfD/).

Comment: Thanks Anthony! Your answer got me on the right track: the div was placed in a google maps infoBox which had 'enableEventPropagation: false' as one of its options. :( Setting it to be true indeed gives the right behaviour.